# Is accessing child class from parent class considered anti-pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, anti-patterns

E.g.

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public Bar f1()
    {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

From the design point of view, do you agree this design is anti-pattern?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?? The fact is that Child class is always added after parent is created.. So, you can't access your Child without knowing which class is the Child... In general it's not a good practice for Parent to access the property of Child..

Comment: Yes, it is probably a bad idea.  I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but I expect that there is probably a better way.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a good way to create a factory function? Using a static function in the abstract class to return child classes seems like a decent enough design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The reason it's bad is because it breaks encapsulation.  If someone changes `Foo`, they realize they could be changing all subclasses.  If someone changes `Bar`, they should never have to think about changing its super classes; its super classes should work the same regardless of the content of `Bar`.